# Rails | how to use destroy_by?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

I'm attempting to destroy some records as part of a transaction (there will only ever be a handful to delete at a time). As such, I'm making a call like the following:

```
MyModel.destroy_by(:foreign_id => "XXX")
```

Unfortunately this is producing some bad SQL and failing. Here's the output from attempting to execute it in the rails console:

```
[3] pry(main)> MyModel.destroy_by(:foreign_id => "XXX")
  MyModel Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "my_model".* FROM "my_model" WHERE "my_model"."foreign_id" = $1  [["foreign_id", "XXX"]]
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  MyModel Destroy (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM "my_model" WHERE "my_model"."" IS NULL
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...TE FROM "my_model" WHERE "my_model"."" IS NULL
                                                             ^

from /home/rwilliams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.6/gems/activerecord-6.1.7.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:672:in `exec_params'
Caused by PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: ...TE FROM "my_model" WHERE "my_model"."" IS NULL
                                                             ^
```

rails version = `Rails 6.1.7.2`

EDIT: There is expected to be more than one record with the specified foreign_id, and I want them all destroyed

EDIT 2: I have also attempted `MyModel.where(...).destroy_all` and get the same error

EDIT 3: The my_model table does not have an id column. This is most likely why the default destroy/delete operations are failing. So I'm looking into how to make it work.... This is a new table, so I do have the option of adding the id column back in if it is ultimately necessary to work with rails

Comment: is it literally saying `"my_model".""`? like an empty column name? do you have a `foreign_id` column in that table? I'm confuse with the `IS NULL` too, you are passing a value right? would be useful if you can share real code, I think you are replacing stuff

Comment: @arieljuod yes - that is literally what it is generating for the DELETE statement, and why it is failing. I replaced the model and column name, and the search value as "XXX", but the rest of it is as-is. I think I have identified the root cause: I created this table without an id column. Providing I can get these destroy/delete operations to work somehow without it, I'd prefer to leave out the id column and stick to my complex key

Comment: yes, that seems to be it, check https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/calling-destroy-on-a-model-that-has-no-id-column/51101, seems like you can use composite_primary_key gem but I've seen that in the past in many projects and I'd recommend to just follow the convention of having an id and avoid headaches

Comment: @arieljuod yea, looking around online it seems that rails has never officially supported composite primary keys. Which seems really odd to me, as it is common to have join tables and such where records can be uniquely identified by a combination of foreign keys or the like. But it seems like it would be more of a hassle to fight the convention. If you'll post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue is trying to delete/destroy a record from a table with no ID column. More details https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/calling-destroy-on-a-model-that-has-no-id-column/51101

An alternative is to use the composite_primary_key gem but I'd suggest adding an id to stick with the rails convention because I've seen issues with that gem in the past during upgrades.